# How to create two panel view in extjs

Tags: extjs, view, panel

i am working in extjs. I want create one view with two panels to show different contents on click event. So how to create such view in extjs?

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)? Click event of what control?

Answer (score 1):

The tabpanel is a view which you can create multiple panels in:

```
Ext.create('Ext.tab.Panel', {
    width: 400,
    height: 400,
    renderTo: document.body,
    items: [{
        title: 'First Panel'
    }, {
        title: 'Second Panel'
    }]
});
```